# What's the difference between a test scenario and test case?

Tags: testcase

After years of not writing tests, I'm going back to basics.

Can someone give me examples of the relationship between test scenarios and test cases?

My understanding to date is, test scenarios are the 'what' we are testing and test cases are the 'how' we are going to test. These test cases are then broken down into positive and negative tests.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399528/whats-the-difference-between-test-scenario-and-test-case --- You can easily find thousand of answers in google

Answer (score 4):

As per my understanding and experience ,

> **Test Scenario** is more about work flow or functionality based.

For example :

- User can add to cart.
- User can able to login.
- User can able to search with product and its description.

> **Test Cases** are part or sub set of one test scenario which are detailed in terms of input, output and process with valid and invalid steps.

For example :

- User can able to add to cart only available products.
- User can not Add to cart out of stock products.
- User can add to cart from search page.
- User can able to login with valid credential.
- User can enter valid input in field  (like email, password criteria).
- User can search product of every category.
- User can search discounted product.
- User can search out of stock products.
- User can search with different criteria like price, type, feature etc.

Hope you find answer.

Answer (score 1):

Test scenario and test case, people interpret them contextually.

My **personal understanding** is:

- Test scenario is we test a functionality via role-playing. E.g., We are testing stackoverflow QA site. The whole testing project can be divided into smaller test scenarios, with each scenario aims to test a single functionality. E.g., one test scenario is to test new user registration. A tester will imagine himself / herself as an end user, starting from registration, creating username and password, choosing which sites you are interested and finally receives a membership.
- Test case is more abstract, more detailed and more refined. The test scenario above can be easily broken down into several smaller test cases: Does the register button lead a user to register a new user page when clicked? Can user name input box accept valid text input / reject invalid ones? Etc.

I would not draw a clear black-white borderline between test scenario and test case. People have been using them interchangeably very often.

Answer (score 0):

Test scenario is the big picture of a main functionality.
Test case is the smallest element which describe the above big picture.

One test scenario can have many test cases.